# jqPlot tickInterval simple issue

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I have a normal chart with yaxis such as below

```
yaxis: {
        show:true,
        min:0,
        max:10000,
        tickInterval: 100
       }
```

but it starts with 0 and moving up by 100 till reaches 10000 but I want the yAxis to go up by 
multiple of 10 such as below:

0, 10, 100, 1000, 10000

is that possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are referring to is called a log axis.  [jqPlot has a plugin for this](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-logAxisRenderer-js.html).

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted.